# Generics in Kotlin and Java with nested classes

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin

Can someone explain, please, why i can't do the code below from Java in Kotlin?

**Java:**

```
public static <T extends ViewGroup> void doSomething(T viewGroup) {
    T.LayoutParams params = viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
fun <T : ViewGroup> doSomething(viewGroup: T) {
    val params : T.LayoutParams = viewGroup.layoutParams
}
```

or

```
fun <T : ViewGroup> T.doSomething() {
    val params : T.LayoutParams = this.layoutParams
}
```

Kotlin just doesn't see *LayoutParams*.

Comment: Imho, Kotlin does "the right thing". Static methods, fields and classes do not get inherited to other classes, thus `T.LayoutParams` does not have a well-defined semantics (other than saying "At execution time `T` is replaces with its upper bound `ViewGroup`). The "correct" (and more reabable way) would be to use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

Comment: To expand on @Turing85's point a bit, Java is only faking here as well and its `T.LayoutParams` means just `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. If one of subtypes of `ViewGroup` has its own `LayoutParams` class defined, it won't be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
fun <T : ViewGroup> doSomething(viewGroup: T) {
    val params = viewGroup.layoutParams
}
```

EDIT:
Well I tried it and you can't do that:

```
val params : T.LayoutParams = viewGroup.layoutParams
```

But you can do that:

```
val params: T = viewGroup
val par = viewGroup.layoutParams
```

Comment: I think that this is the best way of doing this

Comment: Yeah, also tried that, but not what i really wanted, Anyway thanks!